# Does Hazelcast Openfire plugin allows SSL?

Tags: hazelcast, openfire

By default, after installation Openfire Hazelcast plugin has

```
<ssl enabled="false"/>
```

in its config file. My attempt to enable it broke clustering and Openfire log said that

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: SSL/TLS requires Hazelcast Enterprise Edition
```

Is it correct, so there is no way to make Hazelcast plugins using SSL for communications between Openfire nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the Hazelcast Enterprise API is an extension of the Hazelcast API, it might be as simple as recompiling the Openfire Hazelcast plugin with a different Hazelcast dependency.

I did a quick test. The plugin compiles just fine after you swap [the dependency on Hazelcast](https://github.com/igniterealtime/openfire-hazelcast-plugin/blob/6f3e13591a5ec78b4f18476e2e27bb397a702363/pom.xml#L43-L49) with a dependency on the 'enterprise' variant, like this (your version number might vary):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast-enterprise</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>hazelcast</id>
        <url>https://dl.bintray.com/hazelcast/release/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Most of the Hazelcast configuration can be done in the XML file that's already accessible as a stand-alone file in Openfire. There's a good chance that you don't need any code modifications to get things configured in the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this has been attempted before but you can try the following:

1. download the enterprise version of Hazelcast and place the hazelcast jar in `plugins` folder of Openfire. I am not certain about the internals of Openfire but if there exists a maven configuration to import Hazelcast then modify that to load Hazelcast enterprise. Or if nothing else works then try renaming the Hazelcast jar from `hazelcast-enterprise.jar` to `hazelcast.jar`.
2. modify `conf/hazelcast-local-config.xml` to configure license key and security details SSL.
3. Fire away.

Here is a link to Openfire doc for Hazelcast plugin: https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/2.4.0/hazelcast/readme.html#config

Please do update here if this works.

Comment: In my understanding, hazelcast.jar file from a plugin is not the same as hazelcast.jar from Hazelcast IMDG - it contains specifically Openfire plugin code on the top of plain Hazelcast. So, replacing it with hazelcast-enterprise.jar wouldn't help, because there will be no plugin code.

Comment: There is no plugin code inside hazelcast jar, its all Hazelcast codd only. Openfire internally uses Hazelcast APIs.

Comment: Oh, really? Then what is the role of Hazelcast plugin developer?

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring to as 'Hazelcast plugin developer' but on a general note, anyone can develop a plugin for Hazelcast on open-source code. Those plugins are then bundled in a separate jar, not in Hazelcast jar.  Hope that answers your question.

Comment: I'm talking about Openfire plugin built on the top of free version of Hazelcast, not a plugin *for* Hazelcast. https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins.jsp   
 https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/2.4.0/hazelcast/readme.html

Answer (score 0):

Support for TLS/SSL is not included in the open source version of Hazelcast, as the error message indicates it is part of the Enterprise Edition feature set.

https://hazelcast.com/product-features/security-suite/

Comment: Which means that there is no way to make Hazelcast Openfire *plugin* working with SSL.  Even if we buy enterprise Hazelcast IMDG, it won't make plugin enterprize.
Correct?

Answer (score 0):

Correct, purchasing the enterprise edition wouldn't help as far as I can tell.  The Hazelcast (open source) plugin for Openfire is maintained by the folks at Ignite Realtime.  They only support specific versions of Hazelcast as well.